# Heat Capacities ratio equal to 1

Tags: thermodynamics

In which situations can be found the ratio between $C_{P}$ and $C_{V}$ to be equal to the unity? I have read in other places that it happens for liquids and solids because they can be assumed to be incompressible at high temperatures. Thus $C_{P}$ and $C_{V}$ for them have almost same values. I also saw some people giving this same answer when the temperature is very high that the difference between the two heat capacities is very small for solids. But if I want to investigate it in low temperatures, how could I explain this ratio being equal to unity?

Comment: *I also saw some people giving this same answer...* was that here on Physics.SE, a book, another internet source, etc? It might be useful to provide a link (if you can) for some added context.

Comment: I read it in a question posted in Research Gate. [link](http://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_do_gases_have_two_specific_heats_of_Cp_and_Cv_while_solids_and_liquids_have_only_one) .